# Can't Access Web Page Button Wrapped in Span Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to build a web crawler to access this site: https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/

However, I can't manage to get selenium to actually press the submit button, and I'm not sure why.

This is the element :

```
<button type="submit" title="Submit the search" id="yui_3_5_0_1_1503421296451_272">Search</button>
```

This is my code:

```
display = Display(visible=1,size=(800,600))
display.start()
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/harry/Downloads/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/')
search = browser.find_element_by_id('QV1')
search.send_keys(drug)
button = browser.find_element_by_id('yui_3_5_0_1_1503346832009_267')
```

However, it returns the error: 
    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"yui_3_5_0_1_1503346832009_267"}
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.101)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.10.0-32-generic x86_64)

I have used class name, xPath, and ID, and they all return the same error.

Edit: apparently the id changes every time you refresh the page, which is why the id in my code is different than the one I copied from the page.

Comment: The error seems to be telling the truth: the id in the button is not the same as the id in your code.

Comment: Good catch! So, uh, is it possible for the id to dynamically change? Because it changes every time I refresh the page.

Comment: Yes, it is possible for the id to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html, you have mentioned the id as "`yui_3_5_0_1_1503421296451_272`" but in code you mentioned it as "`yui_3_5_0_1_1503346832009_267`". Why so?

Below code will work out for you-

```
button = browser.find_element_by_id('yui_3_5_0_1_1503421296451_272')
```

Just read your comment about dynamic id.

Why don't you give it a shot using xpath

```
button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="qbuild"]/div[1]/div/span/button[1]")
```

Comment: Yup! That xpath works. Thanks so much! Is qbuild just some javascript funkiness for dynamically creating id's?

Comment: No Harry. It's quite simple. Use firebug add-on in firefox to find out the xpath.